# Multiple Firestore admin listDocuments deletions with promises

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out the best way to deal with multiple firestore collection deletions in the most easy and elegant way. Through one function, I am trying to delete two separate collections, and this is my current approach.

```
const deletePost = async () => {
  try{
  const likesPromises = []
  const commentsPromises = []
    
  const deleteLikes = await admin.firestore().collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("likes").listDocuments().then((likes) => {
  likes((like) => {
    likesPromises(like.delete())
  })
})
    
const deleteComments = await admin.firestore().collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments").listDocuments().then((comments) => {
  comments((comment) => {
    commentsPromises.push(comment.delete())
  })
})
    
Promise.allSettled([likesPromises, commentsPromises]).then((result) => {
  //do something here
})
} catch(e){
console.log(e)
}
}
```

So my question is - am I doing this right, or is it another or better way of doing this? I want to make sure that the deletion of likes is prioritized first, and when that is done, and it's certain that everything is deleted, move down to the comments.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use this function for deleting collections:

```js
async function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize = 100) {
  const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
  const query = collectionRef.orderBy("__name__").limit(batchSize);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve).catch(reject);
  });
}

async function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve) {
  const snapshot = await query.get();

  const batchSize = snapshot.size;
  if (batchSize === 0) {
    // When there are no documents left, we are done
    resolve();
    return;
  }

  // Delete documents in a batch
  const batch = db.batch();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
  await batch.commit();

  // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
  // exploding the stack.
  process.nextTick(() => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve);
  });
}

export { deleteCollection, deleteQueryBatch };
```

Always work on such aktions like a collection deletion with batches. Firestore could othervise fail with an error because of to much batch writes.

Just call the function for the collection you want to delete and await the result befofe you continue with the other one.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, Tarik. However, by looking at the code, this is a limit of 100 deletions - correct? Do you happen to know the actual limit? I think I read somewhere that the inital Firebase limit is 500, or has that increased?

Comment: You can increase the limit. I made it 100 just in any case. I would rather put 450 than exactly 500. But you can change it any value youwant.